# Trying to get logo to stick when minimizing browser window

Tags: html, menu, responsive-design

I have added a logo next to my menu bar, but anytime I minimize the browser window it moves and juts behind the menu tabs. I would like it to stay put no matter the size of the browser window.

Here is my HTML code for the logo:

```
<div class="headerlogo"><img src="http://passionpreneurenterprises.com/kerrizane/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/kerrizane2-small3.jpg"></div>
```

Here is the CSS speaking to the logo (I am using Thesis 1.8.4 so that's why the .custom is included):

```
.custom .headerlogo {
    width: 236px;
    margin-left: 160px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Also, here is the CSS code for the menu bar that is next to the logo:

```
.custom .menu {    
    margin-top: -474px;
    margin-left: 165px;
    width: 950px;
    margin-bottom: 11px;
}
```

And here is the CSS code for the header image that is below the menu and the logo:

```
.custom #header_area {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #03989c;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 475px;
}
.custom #header_area .page {
    background:transparent;
}
.custom #header {
    background:url('http://kerrizane.com/newsite/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Kerri-Zane-Header.png') no-repeat center transparent;
    width: 1265px;
    height:400px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 26px;
    margin-left: -140px;
    border-bottom:0;
}
```

Here is a link to the site: http://passionpreneurenterprises.com/kerrizane/about-kerri/ if your browser is maximized, you'll see the logo on the top left and the menu to the right of it. But if you minimize your browser window, you'll see that the logo moves and sits slightly behind the menu, which is not what I want. If I can find a way to make it stay put, that would be ideal. Thanks for any help you can give.

UPDATE: I see what was happening, when I was signed in and viewing the site, the admin toolbar was across the top of the site and making things look off when I was trying to position them. So I've removed the admin toolbar and put the logo where it's supposed to go....

BUT, there's still a problem. When I view it on my PC without the admin tool bar, here is how it looks:

[image: Screenshot of logo on PC]

The picture above is how it's supposed to look. But when I view it on my phone, here is how the logo appears:

[image: Screenshot of logo on phone]

Any suggestions on how to fix this? I have also updated the CSS code of the logo to depict the recent changes I made. Thanks.

Comment: please do provide link for the website

Comment: Hi @sai-ram-sudheer, I have edited my question and added a link to the site along with a bit more of an explanation of the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, I see the logo staying where it is (not behind anything). What browser are you using? But it's good to know single mom can consult an expert about lifestyle

Comment: Hi @Huangism, thanks for the comments on the single mom services. I love what my client is doing. :) I have updated my question with screenshots of what I'm seeing as well as the adjusted CSS code for the logo. Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @Alexis403 it's kind of strange how your entire header is setup. I am not sure why the entire thing needed to be positioned absolutely. If I were you I restructure the entire thing so that the header naturally sits on top. You can then just float the logo to the left and the nav to the right

Comment: @Huangism, can you explain what you mean by the entire header being positioned absolutely? I actually only gave the logo a position of absolute. The actual header image does not have that position. So if you could give me an example of what you mean by restructuring the whole thing so that it naturally sits on top, that would help. I previously tried floating the logo to be left of the menu, but that didn't work at all. Not until I gave it the position of absolute and the top and left properties did it go where I wanted it to. So any example code you can give me to restructure would help.

Comment: @Alexis403 Sorry, I thought the entire thing was absolute but it's not. Still, the html structure in my opinion is not optimal. You have the logo and the nav outside of the header div. I would put them all in a header content div. Float the logo to the left and the nav to the right then you have your image. The design of the header should be a simple 3 element design. I don't know what trouble you were having with it but if you can recreate it in a http://jsfiddle.net then it would be easy for someone to fix it

Comment: @Huangism, I'm at a loss as to how to respond. I'm sure my client doesn't want me to take the time to go through a lot of restructuring like you're suggesting. I was hoping for a simple coding solution to make the logo stay where I want and show correctly on mobile devices. I'll look for some solutions elsewhere. Thank you for your input and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding an answer to this in another forum. I needed to adjust my .headerlogo CSS code to include "position: relative" instead of "position: absolute" (the "position: absolute" was part of the original CSS I posted above in my question). Wanted to share in case anyone else came across this problem. The corrected code I used is as follows:

```
.custom .headerlogo {
height: 71px;
position: relative;
top: -240px;
width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current page seems to be different than the code you've posted, but see if this helps.

Most smartphones will try to scale images so they fit the screen, so if this isn't giving the result you want, you want to override this default behaviour and tell the smartphone what to do.

Try editing the CSS for your header image to something like

```
#teaser-image{
    margin:0 0 10px 0;
    width:90%; /* force image to scale on narrow viewports. to get the results you want, play with this percentage and or the margin values above or a margin on the page */
    max-width: 1265px; /* set max width for image */
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Hi @david-taiaroa, thanks for your answer. I actually found the correct code to use on another forum and it fixed the problem. I posted the answer here.